# How to pass row id to Bootstrap4 model?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, bootstrap-4

I know there few old posts about this issue but none of them is helping me. I'm trying to delete a row via Bootstrap4 model,
unfortunately I have to pass the clicked row value to model in order to delete it can someone please tell me how I can achieve this ?

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <c:forEach items="${anslist}" var="ans">
        <a href="/removeAns/${ans.ansId}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal"></a>
    </c:forEach>        
    
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation </h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure, you want to delete this record ?</p>
          </div>
          <form action="/removeAns/${xxx id here xxx}" method="post">
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" >Delete</button>
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **jquery** for that i.e: whenever `a` tag is clicked get value of `href` and assign that to `action` attribute of form under modal.

**Demo code** :

```js
//onclick of a tag
$("a").click(function(){
//get href value
var hrefs = $(this).attr("href");
console.log(hrefs)
//add to modal form
$("#modal_form").attr('action',hrefs);
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--dummy data added in href -->
<a href="/removeAns/1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Click</a> <br>
<a href="/removeAns/2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Click2</a>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation </h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure, you want to delete this record ?</p>
      </div>
      <!--added id to form-->
      <form action="/removeAns/${xxx id here xxx}" id="modal_form" method="post">
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```